# How do I correct my code to enable my Expect Advisor to take trades?

Tags: mql4

My EA was taking only 1 trade at a time on a single currency pair, it ignores the other pairs till the current trade is closed. I decided to modify it. Now it's no more trading at all.

```
   int Hour = TimeHour(TimeCurrent());
   int DayOfWeek = DayOfWeek();
   int total = OrdersTotal();
   int count=0;

   for(int i=0; i<total; i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS) && OrderSymbol() == _Symbol && OrderMagicNumber()==MagicNumber)
        {
         Alert("Inside Order Select if");
         // Checking if spread is less than 2.0 pips.
         if(current_spread <= AllowableSpread)
           {
            // Checking for days of the week
            if(DayOfWeek >= 1 && DayOfWeek <= 5)
              {
               // Checking for time of the day
               if(Hour >= 3 && Hour <= 20)
                 {
                  if(ADXValue > 25)
                    {
                     if(RSIValue > 50 || RSIValue < 20)
                       {
                        if(PreviousFast<PreviousSlow && CurrentFast > CurrentSlow)
                           ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_BUY, LotSize, Ask, Slippage, Ask-(StopLoss*pips), Ask+(TakeProfit*pips), NULL, MagicNumber, 0, Green);
                        if(ticket<0)
                           Print("OrderSend failed with error #",GetLastError());
                        else
                           Print("OrderSend placed successfully");
                       }
                     if(RSIValue < 50 || RSIValue > 70)
                       {
                        if(PreviousFast>PreviousSlow && CurrentFast < CurrentSlow)

                           ticket = OrderSend(Symbol(), OP_SELL, LotSize, Bid, Slippage, Bid+(StopLoss*pips), Bid-(TakeProfit*pips), NULL, MagicNumber, 0, Red);
                        if(ticket<0)
                           Print("OrderSend failed with error #",GetLastError());
                        else
                           Print("OrderSend placed successfully");
                       }
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: if there's no trade, engine wont get into the loop. `for(int i=0;i<total;i++)` is checked and since `total` equals to zero, it won't go further, cannot select any ticket before alerting on "Inside Order Select if". What to do? loop over open orders to trail or close them, and to count their number if you need. check entry conditions outside that cycle.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel, you are awesome. But the problem is, formerly there wasn't any loop around the code. I used if(OrdersTotal() == 0) to execute my BUY or SELL orders, but it was executing only 1 trade at a time even though I have loaded the robot on many charts. So i decided to put a forloop around it. I'm kind of confused right now.

Comment: I just decided to remove the forloop(), now it's taking only 1 trade, after taking that trade, it ignores the the other pairs till the trade is closed.

Comment: `OrdersTotal()` returns number of trades and orders currently opened at the account, altogether. If you need to get number of trades&orders opened by ea with this particular magic and symbol, add a new function that will count such positions, and call it when necessary (e.g., instead of `if(OrdersTotal()==0)`